# Find mapping between spherical panorama and new image in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have an established spherical 360 view and a new undistorted image

I want to find a mapping between each image pixel and the 360 view, which effectively means finding the θ and ϕ in spherical coordinates for every x and y in cartesian

I have been playing around a bit and I do have a set of matching features in both the 360 and the image, but failed in determining the mapping.

One way I thought of is to use calibrateCamera with the features, then initUndistortRectifyMap and then remap to put the image into the 360. However, I cannot seem to get translation and scaling correct. Furthermore, the maps that are produced are from spherical to cartesian coordinates, rather than the other way around (that is how remap works):

[image: remap equation]

Also, I am not really trying to remove distortion, but rather introduce it, as i am looking for spherical coordinates

The other way I thought of is to use the [Stitcher pipeline](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html) and try to stitch the image into the existing 360 and use the estimateCameraParams to get on the way, but I kinda stranded with lack of documentation

I guess the question is: given a set of corresponding features between two (distorted) images, how can I find a mapping between the two?

Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: "given a set of corresponding features between two (distorted) images, how can I find a mapping between the two?" Are your correspondences perfectly correct or are there outliers left?

Comment: The correspondences are the result of BFMatcher using L2 distance, so they should be pretty correct, however, I think there still may be outliers